# It's 2019. How do you make a Windows installation out of a standalone Java application?

Tags: plugins, maven-3, nsis

A decade ago, I used NSIS to achieve this, but wasn't using Maven.

Now I've been called upon to do it again, but it has to be automatable with Maven.

I've investigated several other questions here, but all of them refer to codehaus nsis plugin projects, and codehaus is long gone.

I can figure out and/or relearn NSIS. But what is the *current* mechanism for integrating it with Maven?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: Our build farms are on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with NSIS on Linux. That being said, here are a couple of links that might be of help.
There is some information on the NSIS documentation site.

[NSIS documentation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixG.html#G.3)

This site might also have some more information to help you out.

[RPM resource mingw32-nsis](https://hany.sk/~hany/RPM/mingw32-nsis.html)

Comment: As I said, I can figure out NSIS. How can you invoke it from Maven?

Comment: @nsayer I have not worked with either Maven nor NSIS on Linux. I did find a link referring to an nsis-maven-plugin:
[nsis-maven-plugin](https://github.com/leif81/nsis-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/site/apt/examples/sample-nsis-project.apt.vm)